# CentOS 7 Yum not seeing available package updates

Tags: linux, centos, yum

This weekend it occurred to me that I likely have several out-of-date packages on my server, so I set about updating them. Two packages require an update: Redis and Git. When I check versions on the server I get old versions:

```
[root]# yum list redis git installed
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 208.74.123.61
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 208.74.123.61
 * cpanel-plugins: 208.74.123.61
 * base: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * epel: mirror.lshiy.com
 * extras: mirrors.xtom.com
 * updates: repos.lax.layerhost.com
Installed Packages
git.x86_64                                   1.8.3.1-23.el7_8                                 @updates
redis.x86_64                                 3.2.12-2.el7                                     @epel
```

A quick check against each package's current releases reveals these to be out of date (Redis is at 6.2 and Git is at 2.34.1 as of this writing).

When I try to update each, yum says no updates are available:

```
[root]# yum update redis
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 208.74.123.61
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 208.74.123.61
 * cpanel-plugins: 208.74.123.61
 * base: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * epel: mirror.lshiy.com
 * extras: mirrors.xtom.com
 * updates: repos.lax.layerhost.com
No packages marked for update
[root]# yum update git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 208.74.123.61
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 208.74.123.61
 * cpanel-plugins: 208.74.123.61
 * base: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * epel: mirror.lshiy.com
 * extras: mirrors.xtom.com
 * updates: repos.lax.layerhost.com
No packages marked for update
```

I've tried `yum clean all`, but no success. I've also tried completely uninstalling the packages and installing them from scratch, but I get the same versions. yum just doesn't seem to be aware of the major version updates. I feel like I'm missing something fairly basic. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **git** and redis versions you stated in your question are the latest available packages from CentOS 7 Updates repo and epel repo.

For git, there's a newer version called git222 or git224 in **IUS repository** (https://ius.io/) as provided on Git official site [here](https://git-scm.com/download/linux) or [here](https://ius.io/setup). It contains prebuilt binaries for x86_64.

Comment: Thanks...I was unaware of IUS. That repo also has a more current version of Redis, as it turns out.